# Test if directed graph is connected

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there a simple built-in way to check if a directed graph is connected?

Now, before you throw `ConnectedGraphQ` or `WeaklyConnectedGraphQ` at me, let me clarify that there are three different qualities of connectedness for directed graphs:

- Weakly connected: the graph would be connected if all edges were replaced by undirected edges.
- Connected: for each pair of vertices $u$ and $v$, there's a path from $u$ to $v$ or a path from $v$ to $u$ (or both).
- Strongly connected: for each pair of vertices $u$ and $v$, there's a path from $u$ to $v$ *and* a path from $v$ to $u$.

The problem is that `ConnectedGraphQ` actually checks for *strong* connectivity on directed graphs, whereas I actually want to know if it's "just" connected.

Some simple test cases:

```
justConnectedQ @ Graph @ {a -> b, c -> b}
(* False *)
justConnectedQ @ Graph @ {a -> b, b -> c}
(* True *)
justConnectedQ @ Graph @ {a -> b, b -> c, c -> a}
(* True *)
```

(I *can* solve this myself, but I'd like to know if there's an elegant/built-in way to do it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my entry:

```
justConnectedQ[g_] := 
 With[{am = AdjacencyMatrix@TransitiveClosureGraph[g], 
   n = VertexCount[g]},
   Total[Unitize[am + Transpose[am]], 2] == n (n - 1)
 ]
```

`TransitiveClosureGraph[g]` creates a (directed) graph in which $u$ and $v$ are connected iff there is a (directed) path from $u$ to $v$.

We take the adjacency matrix of the transitive closure graph, symmetrize it, and check if the result represents a complete graph (i.e. every node is reachable from any other).  We do this by counting the number of `1`s in the matrix (through summing them).

This solution is faster than the one with `GraphDistanceMatrix` and much much faster than the one with `GraphDistance`.  Note that last time I benchmarked `GraphDistance`, it was very slow and computing all shortest path to one vertex took as long as computing all-pair shortest paths with `GraphDistanceMatrix` (i.e. I suspect a performance bug).

On this graph: `g = RandomGraph[{5000, 25000}];` I measure 14 seconds for the `GraphDistanceMatrix`-based solution vs. 2.8 seconds for my solution.  This is still much slower than `ConnectedGraphQ` and `WeaklyConnectedGraphQ` while we know than in theory it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Is there a chance that Mathematica sets some metadata when constructing a graph which is used by `(Weakly)ConnectedGraphQ` so that it doesn't actually have to determine the connectedness then?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Could be, the inner workings of `Graph` are a mystery to me (but I do know that it's complicated with several different kinds of internal representations that can have a sometimes significant impact on performance).  That said, testing connectedness is a simple operation that can be clearly much much faster than my `justConnectedQ` above.  [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) does have testing functions for weak and strong connectedness and it is instantaneous for this graph.

Answer (score 8):

Not super-elegant, but:

```
justConnectedQ = Max @ MapThread[Min, {#, Transpose[#]}, 2] < Infinity & @*
                 GraphDistanceMatrix
```

Answer (score 6):

Create all possible pairs of vertices (and their reverse) and calculate the maximum of their minimum graph distance. Sounds horrible? Looks even more scary in code

```
justConnectedQ[g_?GraphQ] := Max[Min[GraphDistance[g, #1, #2] & @@@
  {#, Reverse[#]}] & /@ Subsets[VertexList[g], {2}]] < Infinity

justConnectedQ@Graph@{a -> b, c -> b}
justConnectedQ@Graph@{a -> b, b -> c}
justConnectedQ@Graph@{a -> b, b -> c, c -> a}
(* False *)
(* True *)
(* True *)
```