# Neighboring nodes in the network

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the graph:

```
graph = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 8, 1 <-> 10, 1 <-> 26, 1 <-> 37, 1 <-> 42, 1 <-> 62, 1 <-> 86, 1 <-> 93, 1 <-> 100, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 7, 2 <-> 9, 2 <-> 12, 2 <-> 14, 2 <-> 17, 2 <-> 18, 2 <-> 25, 2 <-> 36, 2 <-> 41, 2 <-> 46, 2 <-> 50, 2 <-> 55, 2 <-> 72, 2 <-> 75, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 28, 3 <-> 34, 3 <-> 63, 4 <-> 13, 4 <-> 21, 5 <-> 20, 5 <-> 35, 5 <-> 40, 5 <-> 45, 5 <-> 48, 5 <-> 74, 6 <-> 31, 6 <-> 70, 9 <-> 11, 9 <-> 54, 9 <-> 67, 11 <-> 16, 11 <-> 24, 11 <-> 58, 11 <-> 60, 11 <-> 61, 11 <-> 65, 11 <-> 69, 12 <-> 27, 13 <-> 15, 13 <-> 33, 13 <-> 76, 14 <-> 30, 15 <-> 19, 15 <-> 96, 15 <-> 98, 16 <-> 57, 16 <-> 90, 19 <-> 22, 19 <-> 23, 19 <-> 39, 19 <-> 80, 19 <-> 83, 21 <-> 38, 22 <-> 59, 22 <-> 82, 25 <-> 29, 25 <-> 56, 25 <-> 94, 26 <-> 32, 26 <-> 43, 26 <-> 71, 27 <-> 47, 30 <-> 77, 30 <-> 78, 33 <-> 79, 33 <-> 97, 39 <-> 49, 39 <-> 51, 40 <-> 44, 40 <-> 73, 42 <-> 68, 48 <-> 52, 48 <-> 81, 50 <-> 53, 50 <-> 64, 50 <-> 89, 56 <-> 66, 56 <-> 92, 59 <-> 91, 62 <-> 88, 67 <-> 87, 74 <-> 95, 82 <-> 84, 82 <-> 85, 82 <-> 99};

net = Graph[graph, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

Let's choose any node 'g' in the graph:

```
g=19;
```

Let 'r' denote the distance (counted in the number of nodes) from the node 'g':

```
d = GraphDiameter[net]
r = Range[1, d]
```

**How to count all neighboring nodes within radius 'r' from the node 'g' ?**

For example for node g=19 we have 6 nodes for r=1 (nodes:  80,83,22,39,23,15). For r=2 we have 7 nodes: 59,82,49,51,98,96,13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to count all neighboring nodes within radius 'r' from the node 'g' ?

Use [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

`IGNeighborhoodSize` does precisely this and is probably your fastest bet, but I do not have time to benchmark it against other solutions right now.

If you want to do it for multiple distances in one go, use `IGDistanceCounts`,

```
IGDistanceCounts[graph, {vertex}]
```

This gives you the counts of other vertices found at all (unweighted) distances. You can then simply [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) that list to get the result for *all* `r` at the same time.

For weighted distances, use `IGDistanceHistogram`.

Comment: Thanks. And how to count the same as the  'IGDistanceCounts[graph, {vertex}]'  formula but for weighted networks?

Comment: @ralph As I said above, use `IGDistanceHistogram`

Comment: Mr=IGDistanceHistogram[net1, ??] (*for weighted graph *) ???

Comment: @ralph Did you check the documentation? If you checked the documentation and you found it to be unclear, you are very welcome to suggest improvements.

Comment: @ralph The syntax is `IGDistanceHistogram[graph, binSize, {vertex}]` where `binSize` is the bin size used for constructing the distance histogram. You must put the vertex in a list as the syntax also accepts multiple vertices.

Comment: Tahank you. Of course I read the documentation. But the result is at least strange: IGDistanceHistogram[net1, 1, {5}]  vs  IGDistanceCounts[net, {5}]  ===  Drop[IGDistanceHistogram[net1, 1, {5}], 1].

Comment: @ralph What is strange about the result? Please be explicit, show the network, show what you got, show what you think you should have gotten instead.

Comment: If you mean that `IGDistanceHistogram` returns an additional 0, that's because the histogram bins are [0,1), [1,2), [2,3), ...  The first bin will always be empty for a graph whose edges all have weight 1.

Comment: The net1, net2==net are below.

Comment: You did not answer my question ...

Answer (score 7):

I will choose a bit better `GraphLayout` for a tree:

```
net = Graph[graph, VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"];
```

I suggest don't just count directly - get an object - a subgraph - of your query, so you can then run various computations on it and don't need count all over again based on different criteria w/ a different code.

```
nei[v_, d_] := NeighborhoodGraph[net, v, d]
```

Take distance 1:

```
nei[19, 1]
```

[image]

and see it is right:

```
HighlightGraph[net, nei[19, 1]]
```

[image]

Now you can compute whatever you need:

```
VertexList[nei[19, 1]]
Length[%] - 1
```

> {19, 15, 22, 23, 39, 80, 83}
>
> 6

For the distance 2:

```
VertexList[nei[19, 1]]
VertexList[nei[19, 2]]
Complement[%, %%]
Length[%]
```

> {19, 15, 22, 23, 39, 80, 83}
>
> {19, 13, 15, 22, 23, 39, 49, 51, 59, 80, 82, 83, 96, 98}
>
> {13, 49, 51, 59, 82, 96, 98}
>
> 7

### Timings for large graphs

```
net = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[20000, 1]];

nei[v_, d_] := NeighborhoodGraph[net, v, d]

dist15:=Length[Complement[VertexList[nei[#,15]],VertexList[nei[#,14]]]&@RandomInteger[1000]]

Table[AbsoluteTiming[dist15;][[1]], 5]
```

> {0.097359, 0.094737, 0.092589, 0.08872, 0.087478}

Comment: Thank you. The code gives correct results but is memory-consuming for large networks (around 200,000 nodes: net = RandomGraph [BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution [20,000, 1] and d = {1,2,3,4, ..., 15}).

Comment: @ralph is 0.1 seconds is slow? What timings do you need? No criteria for timings is mentioned in your original post.

Comment: Please forgive me. I meant about 200,000 no 20,000 nodes.

Comment: @Szabolcs i was just answering question without performance consideration as it was *not* asked in the OP, which had a tiny graph.  I added benchmark after he made a comment, and then he changed his comment again.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Sorry about the comments, I was wrong: this was actually fixed in 12.0. That is why I deleted them.

Comment: It would still be good to mention that thread: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14522/12 OP is likely using 11.3 or earlier.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK no worries, thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

You could build it using BreadthFirstScan:

```
net = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[200000, 1]];

distance = 
  GroupBy[Reap[
     BreadthFirstScan[net, 
      19, {"DiscoverVertex" -> (Sow[#3 -> #1] &)}]][[2, 1]], 
   First -> Last, Association[{"length" -> Length[#], "set" -> #}] &];
```

Get length:

```
distance[3, "length"]
```

> 1194

```
distance[[All, "length"]]
```

> <|0 -> 1, 1 -> 214, 2 -> 1194, 3 -> 3058, 4 -> 5826, 5 -> 10069,   6
>   -> 15110, 7 -> 19992, 8 -> 23821, 9 -> 24910, 10 -> 24767,   11 -> 21459, 12 -> 17869, 13 -> 13525, 14 -> 9119, 15 -> 5146,   16 -> 2406,
>   17 -> 1025, 18 -> 337, 19 -> 106, 20 -> 34, 21 -> 11,   22 -> 1|>

and set
    distance[21, "set"]

> {182224, 145742, 171910, 124658, 125540, 128520, 196392, 166986, 
>   159530, 196846, 144772}

For weighted graphs:

```
SeedRandom[123];net2 = Graph[net, EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[{1, 20}, EdgeCount[net]]];

edgeWeight[g_, x_, y_] := 
   With[{weight = PropertyValue[{g, UndirectedEdge[x, y]},EdgeWeight]},
       If[NumericQ[weight], weight, 0]]

Clear[dist]; dist[_] := 0;
weights = 
  Reap[BreadthFirstScan[net2, 
     9, {"DiscoverVertex" -> ((dist[#1] = 
           dist[#2] + edgeWeight[net2, #1, #2]; 
          Sow[#1 -> dist[#1]]) &)}]][[2, 1]];

set = Select[weights, #[[2]] <= 5 &];

set[[;; 10]]
```

> {9 -> 0, 66 -> 4, 126 -> 5, 160 -> 5, 190 -> 3, 274 -> 3, 283 -> 4,
>   312 -> 4, 519 -> 5, 537 -> 4}

```
set // Length
```

> 105

Note that BreadthFirstScan approach might not work in general (non tree graphs).

Comment: Amazingly fast, halmir! Any idea why this solution is so much faster than `GraphDistance`, which I would have thought works by `BreadthFirstScan` internally?

Comment: @Roman I had the conviction that `GraphDistance` compute *the entire* `GraphDistanceMatrix` even if you gave it only one vertex. I do not remember what led me to this conclusion though.  I do remember that I put a lot of effort into this functionality area in IGraph/M as I could not use M's built-ins for large graphs.

Comment: @Roman A qucik test tells me that on a tree (which is being benchmarked here) the complexity of `GraphDistance` is *quadratic* in the graph size even when given just one vertex. That should not be so.

Comment: @halmir Can you tell us whether this is a bug and if it is fixable?  The quadratic complexity looks like a bug.

Comment: @Roman I strongly suspect that I may have reported this issue to Wolfram in the past. See e.g. this post I wrote 3 years ago, where I mention it: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109408/12

Comment: @Roman I found my old report. It's also from 3 years ago, but it's not the same issue. It's that `GraphDiameter` keeps the entire graph distance matrix in memory, making this function unusable for large graphs (you'd need many gigabytes). That function *does* need to compute the whole matrix, but not keep it in memory at once. This problem is still unfixed as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs I confirm that for this problem, `BreadthFirstScan` scales with the number of vertices, whereas `GraphDistance` scales with the square. Terrible!

Comment: @halmir Can you change this formula for weighted graphs? Is it possible? Example of graph 'net1' and its weight 'w1' in section 'For weighted network'  below.

Comment: @halmir You would have to multiply the individual transition to the next node by the weight of the edge.

Comment: @ralph I added weighted graph case.

Comment: @halmir Thanks. But the code gives a strange result if we set the weights  '1' anywhere (EdgeWeight -> Table[1,20]). It should give the same result as for the non weighted network.

Comment: @ralph I got the same result. Tested with net2 and vert 4798 in your example.  GroupBy[weights, Last -> First] and distance[[All, "set"]]

Answer (score 3):

To count how many nodes there are at every distance (unsorted `Association`): use this if you want to `Lookup` a particular distance:

```
Counts@GraphDistance[net, g]
```

> <|4 -> 4, 5 -> 12, 3 -> 7, 6 -> 26, 7 -> 20, 2 -> 7, 8 -> 15, 1 -> 6, 0 -> 1, 9 -> 2|>

Look them all up in order:

```
BinCounts[GraphDistance[net, g], {0, d, 1}]
```

> {1, 6, 7, 7, 4, 12, 26, 20, 15, 2, 0, 0}

Comment: Thank you. The code gives correct results but is memory-consuming for large networks (around 200,000 nodes: net = RandomGraph [BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution [20,000, 1] and d = {1,2,3,4, ..., 15})

Comment: Yes if you want only short distances then @szabolcs has better tools available. This `GraphDistance` solution is only good if you want the distances to all nodes in the graph.